# Recuper dados apos submit

Tags: php, javascript

Bom dia Pessoal, tenho um formulário que faz validações no php e não no javascript, e quando acontece um erro executo um history.back() para retornar para o formulário. Que retorna um formulário em branco. Alguém tem alguma ideia para eu não perder esses dados?

**EDIT:** Tenho uma validação baseado numa nota (1 a 10). São 30 perguntas. coloquei apenas uma como exemplo. Executo esse if. Pode ser também fazer essa validação no javascript. Mas não sei como fazer. Me puderem ajudar agradeço.

> HTML

```
<div class="large-2 columns">
   <label>Nota<br>                           
       <input required="" type="radio" value="1" name="14_pesquisa">1 
       <input required="" type="radio" value="2" name="14_pesquisa">2 
       <input required="" type="radio" value="3" name="14_pesquisa">3 
       <input required="" type="radio" value="4" name="14_pesquisa">4 
       <input required="" type="radio" value="5" name="14_pesquisa">5 
       <input required="" type="radio" value="6" name="14_pesquisa">6 
       <input required="" type="radio" value="7" name="14_pesquisa">7 
       <input required="" type="radio" value="8" name="14_pesquisa">8 
       <input required="" type="radio" value="9" name="14_pesquisa">9 
       <input required="" type="radio" value="10" name="14_pesquisa">10
   </label>
</div>
```

> PHP

```
if(($pesquisa14 >= 9 and $pesquisa1 != 0)) {

ok.....

else{

    $retorno = "<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript' TYPE='text/javascript'>
                                    alert('Algo deu errado. Tente novamente');
                                    history.back();
                                </SCRIPT>";

                            echo $retorno;

}
```

Comment: Não envies a página. Usa ajax... sabes como fazer isso? Ou então preenche os campos no PHP para abrir a página já preenchida

Comment: Vou editar minha pergunta pra você entender melhor.

Comment: Recomendo trabalhar a validação do form e a leitura dos dados PHP ($_POST) na mesma página que esta o formulário e assim se ocorrer algum erro você pode setar todos os dados digitados no form novamente. Em caso de sucesso você faz um redirect para a página de sucesso antes de renderizar o form.

Comment: Fabio, estou usando um case "form" para o formulario, e "save" para salvar no banco. No save faço o if. Em MVC como faria isso?

Comment: Sergio, não tenho muito conhecimento em ajax :( pode mostrar um exemplo?

Comment: por MVC vc tb pode jogar o action do form para o mesmo controller q gera o form.
Em todos os inputs do form você terá q colocar  o resultado enviado do form, algo assim:
`
<input required="" type="radio" value="1" name="14_pesquisa" <?php echo (isset($_POST['14_pesquisa']) && $_POST['14_pesquisa'] == 1)?'checked':'';?>>1 
`
entendeu?

Answer (score -1):

Código é simples de exemplo para usar ajax submit

**Arquivo (post.php):**

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    echo $_POST['texto'];
}
?>
```

**Arquivo (index.html):**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="ajax_form">
        <p>Texto:</p>
        <p><textarea name="texto" rows="10" cols="30" placeholder="Descreva um comentario" /></textarea></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="enviar"/></p>
    </form>
    <hr><p>Ajax:</p>
    <textarea id="log" rows="20" cols="70"></textarea>
</body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ajax_form').submit(function(){
        var dados = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "post.php",
            data: dados,
            success: function(testlog) {
                $('textarea#log').text(testlog);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

você pode fazer uma verificação no formulário pra saber se algum radio foi ou não marcado

```
//javascript

function checaPesquisa() {
    sel = document.getElementByName("14_pesquisa").checked;
    if(!sel ){
        alert("Escolha uma opção");
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

e no seu botão de enviar coloca:

```
onClick = "return checaPesquisa()"
```

Comment: Will, o problema não é se ele foi marcado ou não. Para isso eu tenho o required do html. É uma verificação de valor que preciso.